# How to associate a subscriber to an event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make that a subscriber, sub to an certain event
with the following url per example:

```
http://localhost:3001/events/1/subscribers/new
```

but I don't know how to associate event_id when creating a new subscriber

for the moment i'm getting this error:

```
Couldn't find Event with 'id'=
```

in the routes:

```
 resources :events do
    resources :subscribers #url/events/:events_id/subscribers/new
  end

  resources :events
  root 'events#index'
```

in the subscribers controller:

```
def show
  end

  # GET /subscribers/new
  def new
    #puts "Look for me in console\n"
    #puts params.inspect
    @event = Event.find(params[:events_id])
    @subscriber = @event.Subscriber.new
  end

  # GET /subscribers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /subscribers
  # POST /subscribers.json
  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:order_id])
    @subscriber = @event.Subscriber.new order_params
    #@subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subscriber.save
        SubsMailer.new_subscriber(@subscriber).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @subscriber, notice: 'Subscriber was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subscriber }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @subscriber.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

in the new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Subscriber</h1>

<%= render 'form', subscriber: @subscriber %>

<%= link_to 'Back', subscribers_path %>
```

model association:

event.rb:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscribers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

subscriber.rb:

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: /\A\S+@\S+\z/,
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Comment: Maybe there is a better way, but why not use a hidden field in the form getting the required param from the url?

Comment: have u set model associations ?

Comment: @GaganGupta Yeah, look I've edited it to the question.

Comment: okay. Model associations are set pretty well but there's a problem with controller methods. So, wherever you've set `@event.Subscriber.new` change it to `@event.subscriber.new`

Comment: and also. Make it `@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])`

Comment: @GaganGupta I've changed it, and still the same error :/

Comment: can you share generate routes as well ?

Comment: @GaganGupta what do you mean by generate routes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170223/discussion-between-gagan-gupta-and-arb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) will help you to understand what you need to do.

If briefly at first you need to change your models. You could have many to many for Event -> Subscriber association or one to many. One to many is the simplest to show so you need to add this to your Subscriber model:

```
belongs_to :event
```

And this to your Event model:

```
has_many :subscribers
```

Add new migration:

```
def change
  remove_column :subscribers, :events_id
  remove_column :subscribers, 'Event_id'
  add_column :subscribers, :event_id, :integer
end
```

Then in your controller, you should change method calls, as `Subscriber` is a class, not the method.

```
def new
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @subscriber = @event.subscribers.build
end
```

And you should be sure that in your database you have Event with this id.
To check it you can try to debug your controller code:

```
def new
  puts "Event ids: " + Event.all.map(&:id).inspect
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @subscriber = @event.subscribers.build
end
```

In your logs you should have something like:

```
Event ids: [1]
```

Comment: Hey thanks, for the model association I've edited them to the question after Gagan comment,  for the new migration: something is missing the variable t is undefined, should I do: change_table :subscribers do |t| before ?

Comment: I think there already event_id in the subscribers, because i'm getting this error while trying to migrate : duplicate column name: event_id: ALTER TABLE "subscribers" ADD "event_id" integer
/Users/abderrahmane/workspace/Eventmanager/db/migrate/20180502095034_addevent_id

Comment: So you have it in your db, and you don't need additional migration. It would be great if you expose this part of the `schema.rb` to be sure.
Can you show current error with backtrace?

Comment: BTW, if you get "unknown attribute 'event_id' for Subscriber" it is possible that you didn't run migration for this environment.
So if you get this error in tests please do:
`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`

Comment: I think like said Anton I have Event_id not event_id, here is my shema.rb  for the subscribers : 
  create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "Event_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "events_id"
    t.index ["Event_id"], name: "index_subscribers_on_Event_id"
    t.index ["events_id"], name: "index_subscribers_on_events_id"
  end

Comment: Changed migration to make a proper database structure. Please try and let me now about any issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170226/discussion-between-arb-and-alexander-sysuiev).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a typo in your `new` method. You call `params[:eventS_id]` when it should be `params[:event_id]`. Also you don't properly reference your association. it should be `event.subscribers.new`:

```
def new
  #puts "Look for me in console\n"
  #puts params.inspect
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @subscriber = @event.subscribers.build
end
```

Migration:

```
def up
  change_table :subscribers do |t|
    t.remove :Event_id
    t.references :event
  end
end

def down
  change_table :subscribers do |t|
    t.remove :event_id
    t.add :Event_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Keep me posted whether this helps and if you have any additional issues

Comment: When I do that I get an error on the next line (@subscriber = @event.subscriber.new ) saying : undefined method `subscriber' for #<Event:0x00007f885358f8f8> Did you mean? subscribers subscribers=

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if you check my code you will see, that I wrote not `subscriber`, but `subscriberS`. Just copy it properly

Comment: If that helps I sincerely ask you to mark my answer with a tick and upvote for future searches by other people. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: After I added the S, I'm getting this error: unknown attribute 'event_id' for Subscriber.

Comment: Paste please a migration, that was used to create subscriptions table

Comment: Need to add migration and use `build` instead of `new`

Comment: @AlexanderSysuiev Yes, you are right. Updating my answer

Comment: @AlexanderSysuiev here is the migration that was used to create the Subscribers table: 
class CreateSubscribers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :subscribers do |t|
      t.belongs_to :Event, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: Check your `subscribers` table. It looks like you have `Event_id` field, when it should be `event_id`. In fact... just check all the fields that you have in your Event and paste it here

Comment: @AntonTkachov Yes you're right it is Event_id, to change it I need to do a new migration or just change it in the schema.rb ?

Comment: `schema.rb` is just an info file. You can change it in any way, but it will not make any real changes to db. Yes, go with a new migration -- `rails g rename_Event_id_to_event_id_in_subscriptions`

Comment: @AntonTkachov I'm doing this in the migration:     rename_column :subscriber, :Event_id, :event_id
but I get this error: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: event_id: ALTER TABLE "subscribers" ADD "event_id" integer

Comment: @Arb Strange... do you have any data in your subscribers model or is it blank? Added a migration in my answer, that I would use in such case. But it's destrutive and should be used only in case you have no real data in `Subscriber`